# cannot receive out parameter from oracle procedure executed by mybatis

Tags: java, oracle, spring, stored-procedures, mybatis

I develop java application using Spring 3.0.5 and I work with database Oracle using mybatis-spring.

I've an interface for mybatis:

```
public interface SubscriberMapper {
    Subscriber getSubscriberByMsisdn(String msisdn);

    void insertSubscriber(Subscriber subscriber);

    void updateSubscriber(Subscriber subscriber);

    void canCustomerSubscribe(@Param("msisdn") String msisdn, 
                         @Param("responseCode") Integer responseCode);
```

}

mybatis xml content for canCustomerSubscribe:

```
<parameterMap id="canCustomerSubscribeParams" type="map">
    <parameter property="msisdn" jdbcType="VARCHAR" javaType="java.lang.String" mode="IN"/>
    <parameter property="responseCode" jdbcType="NUMERIC" javaType="java.lang.Integer" mode="OUT"/>
</parameterMap>
<select id="canCustomerSubscribe" parameterMap="canCustomerSubscribeParams" statementType="CALLABLE">
    CALL wallet.pkg_wallet_validation.can_customer_subscribe(#{msisdn}, #{responseCode})
</select>
```

and code to execute:

```
public void subscribe(String msisdn) throws InvalidArgumentException {
    Integer responseCode = 0;
    subscriberMapper.canCustomerSubscribe(msisdn, responseCode);
    System.out.println("msisdn: " + msisdn + ", responseCode: " + responseCode);
}
```

When I execute "subscribe" method with invalid "msisdn", I do not receive real out value from procedure. Execution of this procedure in the database returns reponseValue = 1001, but in Java code I receive 0. I turned on debug logging to stout for mybatis and output is:

```
2011-10-19 10:32:46,732 DEBUG [main] (Slf4jImpl.java:28) ooo Connection Opened
2011-10-19 10:32:46,909 DEBUG [main] (Slf4jImpl.java:28) ==>  Executing: CALL wallet.pkg_wallet_validation.can_customer_subscribe(?, ?) 
2011-10-19 10:32:46,911 DEBUG [main] (Slf4jImpl.java:28) ==> Parameters: 509999999(String), 0(Integer)
msisdn: 509999999, responseCode: 0
```

When I change in "subscribe" method responseCode = null, I receive and error:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Error setting null parameter.  Most JDBC drivers require that the JdbcType must be specified for all nullable parameters. Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type
; uncategorized SQLException for SQL []; SQL state [null]; error code [17004]; Invalid column type; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found solution. Map must be user instead of two parameter in canCustomerSubscribe method.

```
 void canCustomerSubscribe(Map<String,Object> params);
```

mybatis xml content:

```
<select id="canCustomerSubscribe" parameterType="java.util.HashMap" statementType="CALLABLE">
    CALL wallet.pkg_wallet_validation.can_customer_subscribe(
    #{msisdn, jdbcType=VARCHAR, javaType=java.lang.String, mode=IN},
    #{responseCode,jdbcType=NUMERIC, javaType=java.lang.Integer, mode=OUT})
</select>
```

(I need to add the commas between arguments attributes)

calling it from subscribe service method:

```
public void subscribe(String msisdn) throws InvalidArgumentException {
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put("msisdn", msisdn);
    params.put("responseCode", null);
    subscriberMapper.canCustomerSubscribe(params);
    System.out.println(params.get("responseCode"));
}
```

Comment: I correct the syntax of the XML file, I need to add the commas between arguments attributes!